Ansible playbook with usera need to use task service for restart myservice with userb
In my Ansible script execute with my user, I need to restart a service activemq with non-root user activemq.
- name: Recharger le service si la configuration de ACTIVEMQ a changé.
  service:
    name: activemq
    state: restarted
    enabled: true
  become: true
  become_user: activemq
  become_method: sudo
  when: activemq_conf is changed

I added a specific sudoers configuration for authorize activemq to restart service.
activemq ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl restart activemq, /bin/systemctl reload activemq, /bin/systemctl start activemq, /bin/systemctl stop activemq, /bin/systemctl enable activemq

But task don't work
"msg": "Unable to start service activemq: Failed to start activemq.service: Connection timed out\nSee system logs and 'systemctl status activemq.service' for details.\n"

Each time it's like su command ask for password ...
I try adding sudoers and/or polkit rules for authorize myuser to do su - activemq or call systemctl without succes.s
If I run this command on server with my user, it's OK.
sudo -u activemq sudo /bin/systemctl restart activemq

But I need to keep the second sudo. Otherwise, password is asked.
Who can I resolve this?

That's because the command that will be executed and which would need to be put into the sudoers file is different. See background and possible solution under "Missing sudo password" error with Ansible Error.
